# Mac OSX High CPU % Usage - Draining battery and heating!

Tags: macos, battery, cpu

For the past year I've experienced high CPU usage on CORE process (activity monitor) and also extreme heating, with cooling fans at maximum, draining my battery every single day.

My home banking requires a security module to be installed, named WARSAW (DIEBOLD, Gas Tecnologia).

So I came across this solution: https://macmagazine.com.br/2017/11/18/o-modulo-de-seguranca-de-bancos-pode-estar-detonando-o-seu-mac-saiba-como-so-ativa-lo-quando-necessario-neste-tutorial/

I know many many people have this problems and it was really really hard to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://macmagazine.com.br/2017/11/18/o-modulo-de-seguranca-de-bancos-pode-estar-detonando-o-seu-mac-saiba-como-so-ativa-lo-quando-necessario-neste-tutorial/

1. Use the Finder to go to /library/LaunchAgents/, on the root of the main driver and delete the file com.diebold.warsaw.user.plist.
2. Use the Finder to go to /users/USER/library/LaunchAgents/, on the user's folder and delete the file com.diebold.warsaw.user.plist.
3. Kill the running application with the Terminal command sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.diebold.warsaw.plist.
4. Uninstall the loser module sudo /usr/local/bin/warsaw/uninstall.sh
5. Restart your mac.